# Oracle socket read time out error in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I have created a spring boot application. When I put load on the application after sometime load on database server started increasing and I got started socket read time out error.

```
2016-10-24 21:56:10 [pool-3-thread-296] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - IO Error: Socket read timed out
2016-10-24 21:56:10 [pool-3-thread-296] ERROR 
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
```

Here is the properties file details of Springboot application

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:1521:<dbname>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.initial-size=100
spring.datasource.maxActive=1500
spring.datasource.validationQuery=select 1 from dual
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy

spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements-cache-size=500
spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements=500
```

Since the error is very generic , I am not able to figure out why I am getting socket read timeout exception.
I also need to know what does "[pool-3-thread-296]" mean in exception log ?

Comment: Read it as: "Can't establish a connection to the database". The error cannot tell you why, that is something that needs to be figured out from a network perspective. Might be that the server isn't running on the IP/port you have led to believe it is running on. Might be that it isn't running at all. Might be that a firewall is blocking it. Can be any number of reasons.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this? This worked for me

https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/